# GXT : Cancel click event on grid header

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

I have a grid like [this one](http://www.sencha.com/examples/#ExamplePlace:basicgrid) . The default behavior of this widget is to sort the column when clicking on the header. I want to disable that, and leave only the options in the context menu.

```
grid.addHeaderClickHandler(new HeaderClickHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onHeaderClick(HeaderClickEvent event) {
        event.getEvent().cancelBubble(true);
        event.getEvent().preventDefault();
        event.getEvent().stopPropagation();
        Window.alert("Event caught");
    }
});
```

The alert gets displayed before the sorting. But when clicking `Ok` the default behavior kicks in.

Do you have any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Comment: I don't have the solution, but found a old post from 2009 about something similar: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?61874-how-could-i-disabled-header-click-when-gird-can-sortable

Comment: Thank you but the post is for extjs, not gxt.

Comment: That's why I said similar :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found it `grid.getView().setSortingEnabled(false);`. This will disable the sorting when clicking on the header, but keep the menu items in place.

Answer (score 2):

A solution that might work is to use the NativePreviewHandler, something similar to

```
Event.addNativePreviewHandler(new NativePreviewHandler()
    {
        @Override
        public void onPreviewNativeEvent(final NativePreviewEvent event)
        {
            if (event.getTypeInt() == Event.ONCLICK)
            {
                Element targetElement = Element.as(event.getNativeEvent().getEventTarget());
                if (!tableHeader.asWidget().getElement().isOrHasChild(targetElement))
                {
                    event.getNativeEvent().stopPropagation();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Brute but it might do the trick. Upvoted. I will test this and come back.

Answer (score 1):

In order to disable sorting you have to configure the column(s) to forbid sorting.

E.g. if you create a column like this (based on the source code from http://www.sencha.com/examples/#ExamplePlace:basicgrid)

```
ColumnConfig<Stock, String> symbolCol = new ColumnConfig<Stock, String>(props.symbol(), 100, "Symbol");
```

disable sorting by adding

```
symbolCol.setSortable(false);
```

See http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/gxt-3.0.0/javadoc/gxt/com/sencha/gxt/widget/core/client/grid/ColumnConfig.html#setSortable%28boolean%29 for documentation (and other options).

Comment: Upvoted for now since I haven't tested it. I will mark it when I do. But I have a question. Doesn't `setSortable(false);` disable the sorting altogether? Although I want to disable it when clicking the header, I want to still be able to sort it by clicking the menu item of the context menu. Thank you for your help

Comment: You could still manually trigger sorting by directly interacting with the ListStore and calling grid.getHeader().updateSortIcon.

Comment: I've tested it and the `setSortable(false)` it fixed the header, but as expected it also removes the sorting menu items of the context menu, which is something I absolutely do not want. Do you know any other solution? Is there a way to just cancel the click event on the header?